# Build error when create a new project with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

#### Question:

When I use Android Studio to create a new project according to the [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project), some errors occur when compile the project:

The error image:

[image: error image]

I have never edit any configuration about gradle or other files, and here is the log file:

```
2018-11-19 20:33:08,967 [d thread 3]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'MyFirstApp'. 
2018-11-19 20:33:08,976 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
2018-11-19 20:33:09,534 [d thread 3]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (1 m 17 s 461 ms) 
2018-11-19 20:33:09,604 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2018-11-19 20:33:09,604 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project '/Users/tanrui/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp' MyFirstApp 
2018-11-19 20:33:09,657 [cessToken]]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2018-11-19 20:33:09,832 [d thread 2]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 1ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,620 [d thread 2]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 788ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,622 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0.001 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,622 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,623 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0.001 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,624 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 0.000 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,624 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0.000 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,624 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0.000 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,625 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,625 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,630 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,632 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0.007 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,632 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-11-19 20:33:10,633 [d thread 2]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0.001 s. 
2018-11-19 20:33:11,138 [d thread 1]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2018-11-19 20:34:01,446 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - <html>You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "127.0.0.1".<br>This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy<br>This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.<br>(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.)
```

#### Something about my work environment.

- Android studio 3.2.1
- gradle 4.6
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

#### Some methods I've tried but didn't work.

There are many similar questions on Google, as they said that I should setting the proxy for Android Studio(maybe only need in CN). In fact, I've set ShadowSocks properly and configure Android Studio as below:

The proxy configuration image:

[image: proxy configuration image]

Test proxy image:

[image: test proxy image]

Test success image:

[image: test success image]

But it still doesn't work.

#### Some codes:

**gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**build.gradle(Project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(Module):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "top.guitoubing.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

#### Hopes

If anyone of you know where is the problem, please give me an advise or if there is anything I didn't express clearly, just questioning me.
Hope for your help! Thanks.

Comment: So sorry to disturb you! I've corrected it.